# How do I configure s3cmd from Ansible?

Tags: ansible, s3cmd

I have a playbook which clones a repo and executes a Python script, which uses `s3cmd` and `os.popen()` to run an s3cmd command.

However, it says `s3cmd: command not found`, even though I have installed s3cmd.  Maybe it is because I have not configured them.

Error: `"stderr": "sh: s3cmd: command not found",`

So, how do I configure s3cmd inside the dynamically created EC2 instances.

[I already have an `environment` set for the AWS keys. Is there any way I can use them for this too?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fully specifying the path to s3cmd (e.g., /usr/bin/s3cmd)  everywhere.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html the environment settings can be used on the playbook/play/task level.